# What is the difference between destructor and allocator::destroy

Tags: c++, memory, vector, destructor

Having this class:

```
template<class T>
class Vec
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef T* const const_iterator;
    typedef T value_type;

    Vec() {
        create();
    }
    explicit Vec(size_t n, const T& val = T()) {
        create(n, val);
    }
    void clear() //here, I cannnot destroy nither by alloc.destroy, nor i->~T()
    {
        if (data)
        {
            iterator i = avail;
            while (i != data)
            {
                alloc.destroy(--i); //or i->~T()
            }
        }
        avail = data;
    }
    ...
private:
    iterator data;
    iterator avail;
    iterator limit;

    std::allocator<T> alloc;
    void create();
    void create(size_t n, const T &val);
    ...
```

Now I will use the `clear` functino (version of `std::allocator<T>::destroy`, not destructor) in main file:

```
#include "vec2.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Vec<string> v(3, "abc");
    v.clear();
    cout << v[2] << endl;
}
```

1.)
Now even I have cleared the `Vec` class (performing destructor for all elements in it), I can still output `v[2] -> "abc"` even thought the string should perform the destructor and thus be empty string.

2.) should I use `alloc.destroy(i)`, where the `i` is `T*`, or should I use `i->~T()`?

Comment: Destroying an object means you are not allowed to look at it afterwards. There is no reason, for example, for the implementation to bother writing a bunch of `0`s into that memory, so often that memory address will still contain the same data as before. That doesn't mean you are allowed to look at it though. This is called [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: And does `destroy` equal `destruct` ?

Comment: "the string should perform the destructor and thus be empty string" is a false conclusion. The correct one is: "and thus I am not allowed to use it anymore, this is UB".

Comment: @freakish what is then `std::string::~string()` suppose to do then?

Comment: We can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/destroy) that calling `allocator::destroy()` is basically the same as calling the destructor on the pointed-to object.

Comment: @milanHrabos nothing? Something? Who cares as long as it destroys the object and frees memory?

Comment: @BoBTFish, ok so what should I choose then, in my case?

Comment: @freakish I do because every class, or non-POD has specific destructors, so does `std::string`

Comment: @milanHrabos Hard to say without sitting down and going over the design of the whole component with you to be honest. I would say, if you want to support allocators, do it completely and correctly. That is surprisingly hard, so if this is just a learning exercise, I'd suggest not trying to use allocators at all.

Comment: @milanHrabos consider this: you have a string. Why would you ever "clear" the string on destruction? What purpose that this cleaning serve? It only wastes instructions. The same space can be reused later. And this happens all the time, people design stuff to be as efficient as possible. But this is an irrelevant implementation detail. What is relevant is that you are not allowed to access memory after deallocation.

Comment: This *very good* answer is closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/5910058

Comment: `allocator::destroy` has been obsoleted in C++17 and removed in C++20 (for a good reason!). There is no reason to ever call it in new programs.